# How can I listen for changes to sub-property using PropertyChanged.Fody?

Tags: c#, inotifypropertychanged, fody, fody-propertychanged

I use the awesome weaver [PropertyChanged.Fody](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) for avoiding INotifyPropertyChanged boilerplate. I define dependent properties like this:

```
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
public string FullName { get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; } }
```

However, this method does not work with subproperties. What I want to achieve is something like this:

```
public Person MyChild { get; set; }
public string ChildName { get { return MyChild.FullName } }
```

When `MyChild.FirstName` changes, I want `ChildName` to notify that it is also changed. Is is possible to achieve this without explicitly subscribing to `MyChild.PropertyChanged` and manually calling `RaisePropertyChanged("ChildName")`?

Comment: As far as I can tell, this problem falls outside the realm of what PropertyChanged.Fody can solve. I've started looking at functional reactive programming via Reactive Extensions, seems promising so far.

Comment: Bello I'm in the same situation... Have you got far on this?

Comment: @advapi I found the easiest way was to use some kind of subscription like MvvmCross' `WeakSubscribe()`: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/3.5/CrossCore/Cirrious.CrossCore/WeakSubscription

Comment: `PostSharp` can solve this case. see: https://doc.postsharp.net/inotifypropertychanged-dependencies